# Does SOAP 1.2 support SOAP 1.1 version as well?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using soap 1.2 for my webservice application.
When I send a soap request using 1.2 namespace and content-type:application/soap+xml I get a successful response.

But when I send the request using 1.1 namespace and content-type:text/xml I get VersionMismatch error.

SOAP 1.1  namespace : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope - Content-Type:text/xml
SOAP 1.2 namespace  : http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope - Content-Type:application/soap+xml

Below is the soap 1.1 request and response message.

1) Does my application support SOAP 1.1 version ?
(Because although I am using SOAP 1.2 when I send SOAP 1.1 request I get VersionMismatch but the fault string is misleading).

2) In case if there is backward compatibility ie SOAP 1.2 also supports SOAP 1.1 is there a way to disable this ?

SOAP 1.1 request:

```
<soap:Envelopexmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

SOAP 1.1 response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Value>soapenv:VersionMismatch</soapenv:Value>
         </soapenv:Code>
         <soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Only SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2 messages are supported in the system</soapenv:Text>
         </soapenv:Reason>
         <soapenv:Detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'm having the same exception from a Rhapsody server when I try to send a message using correspoding xmlns as per the w3.org.